# How to filter INSIDE foreign key set?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

There are two models

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()

class Vote(models.Model):
    cas_id = models.IntegerField()
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='votes')
```

I want to get ALL questions. Every question's votes set should include only votes with `cas_id=123`. Some question's votes set may be empty.
SQL query looks like:

```
with user_votes as (
  select *
  from votes
  where cas_id = 123
)
select *
from question q left join user_votes uv on q.id = uv.question_id;
```

How can I do it via django-ORM in one query?

I tried following.

1. `.filter(votes__cas_id=123)` excludes extra rows.
2. 2 queries and some code work OK.

Comment: `Question.objects.filter(votes__cas_id=123)` should work

Comment: @Stargazer your query filters questions. So in result only questions with particular votes will be presented. But I want to get ALL questions as in SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A prefetch with a separate filter in the query should handle this:

```
Question.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch('votes', queryset=Vote.objects.filter(cas_id=123)))
```

Comment: it works. It makes two db hits, not one, but looks better than two separate calls to Question and Vote and merging in code with hands. Thank you.